# lookup for especial node in if condition XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Hi I have trouble with a if condition in my code. Well, to be accurate here is the XML file:

```
<root name="fristLevel">
    <test name="secondaryLevel_1">
        <medium>
            <scribe>
                <cloude>
                    something is here
                </cloude>
            </scribe>
            <demo>
                something is here
            </demo>
        </medium>
    </test>
    <test name="secondaryLevel_2">
        <medium>
            <demo>
                something is here
            </demo>
        </medium>
    </test>
</root>
```

What I am looking for is an IF condition which does something if `medium` has a child node as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/test">
    <xsl:if test="medium/scribe/node()">
        <!-- something here  -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it does not work for me. Does anybody has another any better idea?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: It's working may be your template and parent of this for-each not matched and you will not get result. Check once! I am using oxygen XML editor.

Comment: Maybe add a `/` before `root/test` to make it `/root/test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea looks well, but maybe you failed to place this code
in a proper place.

Even if your code were placed in a template matching the whole
document `/`, the output would not be a well-formed XML,
because XML document must containt a **single** node
at the main (root) level.

So probably:

- The script should containt a template matching `root`
  (your main node).
- The tags for the main node should be copied (`<xsl:copy>`),
  otherwise the output would not have any **single** main node.
- And finally, **within this** (between `<xsl:copy>` and
  `</xsl:copy>` tags) there should be placed your `<xsl:for-each`
  loop.
- The script should include also the *identity template*.

Something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="test">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:if test="medium/scribe/node()">
            <HasScribe><xsl:value-of select="medium/scribe"/></HasScribe>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

As you can see, I also added `xsl:apply-templates` for attributes,
so that in the output it can be seen, from which source element
has been generated particular output element.

For a working example, with slightly changed your XML, see http://xsltransform.net/ei5Pwjn